# Translating "break" (during work)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, sustantivos, vocabulario

In the US, it is common for workers to take a half-hour or hour lunch break in the middle of the day, plus two ten or fifteen minute breaks in the morning and afternoon. Spanish has many words that can be translated "break" (descanso, recreo, pausa, entreacto, interrupción, vacaciones, etc).

What is the best way to describe a break from work (during the day, not an extended vacation) in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spain, the *formal* term would be "**descanso**". The [Estatuto de los Trabajadores Art 34.4](http://noticias.juridicas.com/base_datos/Laboral/rdleg1-1995.t1.html#a34) states:

> 4. Siempre que la duración de la jornada diaria continuada exceda de seis horas, deberá establecerse un **período de descanso** durante la misma de duración no inferior a quince minutos. Este **período de descanso** ...

However, it is *informally* referred to as [**pausa para el bocadillo**](http://www.pymesyautonomos.com/legalidad/la-pausa-para-el-bocadillo-no-es-tiempo-efectivo-de-trabajo):

> El Tribunal Supremo acaba de ratificar en una sentencia que la **pausa para el bocadillo** no es tiempo efectivo de trabajo al amparo de...

Comment: Buena respuesta como las otras que haz hecho. Te sugeriría que edites tu perfil y nos des un nombre más "humano" algo así como "Juan formerly known as user13560" :-)

Answer (score 10):

I think the best translation would be *descanso*. The [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=descanso) lists:

> Quietud, reposo o pausa en el trabajo o fatiga.

as one of the meanings of *descanso*.

- *recreo* would probably be best translated as ["recess"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recess_%28break%29);
- *pausa* is closer to "pause";
- *entreacto* is closer to ["intermission"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermission);
- *interrupción* is closer to "interruption";
- *vacaciones* is closer to "vacation";

Comment: It might depend on what country you want to use this in. In Mexico I only ever heard *pausa* in this exact sense though many of the people I knew who used it were actually volunteers from Germany so their usage might've been influenced by German. Personally I only used *descanso* to refer to a rest, but I could've been translating too literally.

Comment: Here in Spain the only usage I have noticed is "descanso"

Comment: "Receso" is also be possible but it's more formal.

Comment: En la mayoría de las circusnstancias,especialmente en contextos laborales,  break será bien entendido tal cual.

Comment: En Chile, en reuniones, conferencias, etc., se suele decir "vamos a hacer un cofi", por acortamiento de la expresión _coffee break_. Esto es independiente de que efectivamente se tome café. (Es bastante ridículo, ojalá que sea una moda pasajera.)

Answer (score 3):

En el Río de la Plata y seguramente en el resto de Latinoamérica también, refiriéndose a un trabajo, informalmente se utiliza el término **descanso** mientras que una opción más formal sería **receso**. En caso de tratarse de estudiantes, se utiliza **recreo**.

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Gracias por ella y bienvenido a [spanish.se].

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Entrevisto a muchas personas de América Latina que trabajan en los Estados Unidos (mayormente mexicanos que no tienen mucha educación formal)  sobre temas y quejas laborales, y encouentro que la mayoría utiliza el término inglés... "break". Por ejemplo, "nunca me dan mis break ni mi lonche..."

Siempre utilizo "descanso" (y "almuerzo" por supuesto, cuando hablo de "lunch break") y me entienden sin problemas, pero es común que sigan respondiendo con "break".